# How to retrieve multiple dynamic textbox values from angularjs controller into c# web method

Tags: c#, arrays, angularjs, postgresql, webmethod

[image: Here i have textboxes that are dynamic when i add another product. I only give input into the textbox, after entering the values into the textbox and clicking on save button, the textbox values should be stored as an array into the controller. The controller should fetch the multiple textbox values and store as an array and should pass into the c# web method.]

### Product.aspx

Here i have textboxes that are dynamic when i add another product. I only give input into the textbox, after entering the values into the textbox and clicking on save button, the textbox values should be stored as an array into the controller. The controller should fetch the multiple textbox values and store as an array and should pass into the c# web method.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="PR in ProductList | orderBy:'productid'">
                           <th data-width="5%">
                                <h2>{{PR.productid}}</h2>   
                            </th>
                            <th data-width="15%">
                                <h2>{{PR.productname}}</h2>
                            </th>
                            <th data-width="15%">
                                 <input type="text" name="productprice" data-ng-model="productprice[$index]" value="{{PR.productprice}}"/>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" data-ng-click="Save()" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"><span>Save</span></button>
                    </div>
```

### productcontroller.js

What i have tried is, i made an array of that textbox values by using ng-model productprice. And i stored the entire array into the variable products2 and passed into the data.

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", [])
    app.controller("ProductController", function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.Save = function () {
            $scope.productprice = [
                {
                    productprice: 'productprice'
                }
            ]
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'Product.aspx/save',
                headers: {

                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                },
                data: {'products2': $scope.productprice }
            }
            $http(httpreq).then(function (data) {
                if (data = "true") {
                    alert("added successfully.");
                }
            }, function () { alert("data not added") });
        };
    });
```

### Product.aspx.cs

Here what i have tried is i fetched "products2" which is an array from the controller and trying to populate in c# web method.

1. Using Transaction

When i click the save button, all the textbox values should save into the database table of the same column with different rows. Say i have a column called productprice, and this column should contain the above textbox values into different rows one by one.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
    public static void save(decimal[] products2) //This "products2" is an array value fetched from the controller. 
    {
        decimal[] productprice = products2; //i again stored this into variable.
        using(NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            NpgsqlTransaction myTrans;         
            myTrans = con.BeginTransaction();
            cmd.Transaction = myTrans;
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into quotation_details2(productprice)" + "values (,@productprice);";      

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productprice", productprice.ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myTrans.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine("All records are written to database.");
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException)
            {
                myTrans.Rollback();

                Console.WriteLine("Neither record was written to database.");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con != null)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
            }  
        }
    }
public class ProductInfo
{
    public decimal productprice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like this

```
 $scope.save = function () {

            var res1 = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ProductList.length; i++) {
                var res = { productid: parseInt($scope.ProductList[i].productid), productprice: $scope.ProductList[i].productprice };
                res1.push(res);
            }
            console.log(res1);
            var requestInfo = { products2: res1 };
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'Product.aspx/save',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                },
                data: {
                    qid: $scope.qid,
                    vendorname: $scope.vendorname,
                    from: $scope.from,
                    to: $scope.to,
                    products2: res1
                }
            }
            $http(httpreq).then(function (response) {
                swal("Added Successfully", "", "success");    // try this sweetalert        
            }).catch(function (error) {
                $.alert({
                    title: 'Alert!',
                    content: 'Not Successfull',
                    position: {
                        my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: window
                    }
                });    
            });
        }; 

## .cs file ##
```

You need to modify your cs file

```
public class ProductData
{
    public int qid { get; set; }
    public string vendorname { get; set; }
    public string from { get; set; }
    public string to { get; set; }
    public List<InitialInfo> productInfo { get; set; }
}

public class InitialInfo
{
    public int qid { get; set; }    
    public int productid { get; set; }
    public string productname { get; set; }
    public string productprice { get; set; } 
}
 public static void save(int qid, string vendorname, DateTime from, DateTime to, ProductInfo[] products2)
    {

        using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            NpgsqlTransaction myTrans = conn.BeginTransaction();


            try {

            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into public.quotation2(qid, vendorname, from_date, to_date)"
                                   + " values (@qid, @vendorname, @from, @to);", conn, myTrans))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qid", qid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendorname", vendorname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", from);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", to);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd1 = new NpgsqlCommand("insert into quotation_details2(qid,productid,productprice) values(@qid,@productid,@productprice)"
                                                       , conn, myTrans)) 
            {
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd1.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@productid", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@qid", qid));
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@productprice", NpgsqlDbType.Numeric));
                    for (int i = 0; i < products2.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var pID = 0; var pPrice = "";
                        pID = products2[i].productid;
                        pPrice = products2[i].productprice;
                        cmd1.Parameters[0].Value = pID;
                        cmd1.Parameters[2].Value = pPrice;
                    NpgsqlDbType.Json.ToString()).Value = products2[i].productid.ToString();
                      NpgsqlDbType.Json.ToString()).Value = products2[i].productprice.ToString();
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                myTrans.Commit();
                Console.WriteLine("records are written to database.");
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException e)
            {
                myTrans.Rollback();
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Neither record was written to database.");
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }}
```